# Theme based altering of default image-style for the same node-type and view-mode

Tags: 7, theming, media, entities

OK, After some research and since Domain_views module seems to be a little bit buggy (printing always default Domain ID no matter what), I think this is the base question solving my problem the other way around with 2 domains and 2 themes using the same nodes from same node-type, but they both need different image-styles because of their 2 different themes:

***How do I alter the given image-style of a given node-type in its default full-node view-mode in the .tpl files of a theme, to have 2 different used image-styles in 2 different themes by the same node-type and the same view-mode?***

I've tried to find example themes doing it and I heard of Entity view mode to add custom view modes, but I am still not sure if I am on the right tracks. Actually I only need another image style (size) for the same node-type and the same view mode but in 2 different themes since Domain Access gives me hard times to solve this with conditional view modes or Views displays.

From what I understood there are 2 ways:

- a custom view mode for the same node type and a function in the theme telling the node-type to rather use this view mode
- or only a image-style altering in the node--full.tpl.php but I can't find a good example explaining it.

The very basic question to research for me is: how to alter image-styles in the code of the theme layer? Is this correct?

Any help would be very appreciated! Thank you very much for any hint.

Answer (score 0):

Well after reforming my question 3 times and rethinking what the actually question should be like to find a solution, I came to the conclusion that the Domain_views module is completely broken (ALL Domain views fields always output the default Domain ID/name/path no matter what), and that the theme layer node--view-mode.tpl.php altering approach is not generic enough to have this functionality in other use-cases.

So I found a nice trick, which maybe also helps others to change field styles in a given steady node-type and same view mode under certain conditions, but it needs Views module:

Use the [Views_conditional](http://drupal.org/project/views_conditional) module and use your fantasy to get the needed result. :-) That easy!

In my case I was able to turn off the Domain_views module completely (finally!) and have used the absolute path setting from the content:path views field to change the image-style under the condition, that the path includes a given pattern of one of my domains. I have 2 image fields (excluded in Views) and a conditional field showing one of them if needed, e violá! :-) My image style changes in the 2 different domains by the same given node-type and node-view-mode! Awesome

Views as a full node view mode designer... I never stop learning. ;-)